# failed to emit precompiled header in Xcode 10.1

Tags: swift4.2

I have updated the code from swift3 to swift4.2 and I was getting warnings so I updated the podfile by reinstalling all the pods and now I am getting the error as:

```
failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/palak.garg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mySocialChemist-gtbbctpiuhpyzngmqbevmscwbcet/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/mySocialChemist-Bridging-Header-swift_14WYMBJ6PJP8W-clang_38EYTCGHX7TO1.pch' for bridging header '/Users/palak.garg/Desktop/Code/April current project/Send-a-Script---IOS 2 2 2/mySocialChemist/Classes/mySocialChemist-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Where `mysocialChemist` is my project name and `mySocialChemist-Bridging-Header.h` is bridging header file. Also Showing Recent Messages:

```
/Users/palak.garg/Desktop/Code/April current project/Send-a-Script---IOS 2 2 2/mySocialChemist/Main/mySocialChemistAppDelegate.h:16:9: 'Braintree/BraintreeVenmo.h' file not found
```

Where Braintree/BraintreeVenmo is pod I used.

Also, I am getting a warning at the terminal where I updated the pod as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

I tried the following points but nothing worked for me:

1. I uninstall the pods and reinstall then clean and build the project but nothing worked.
2. Also in Xcode > Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Build options both are checked as shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gM0i.png).
3. Clean the derived data and build the project.
4. Target > Build Settings > Swift compiler - Custom flag > Other swift flags set $(inherited) as [in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHayh.png).
5. Target > Build Settings > preprocessor macros set $(inherited)as shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy8SG.png)

Thanks in advance.